# бот не отправляет массивы aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

Недавно я писал телеграм бота угадай число. Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать систему рейтинга для игроков. В файле rating.txt хранятся два массива - один с именами игроков, другой - с их рейтингом.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['rate'])
async def rate(message: types.Message):
    f = open('rating.txt')
    data = f.readline()
    users = f.readline()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'команда работает' + str(data), users)
```

Но при выполнении данного кода вылазит ошибка aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Unsupported parse_mode. Что это такое и как ее исправить?
P.S. Сообщение "команда работает" временное, так как проверял код.

Comment: В файле есть "плохие" символы?
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/131

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже третий аргумент send_message() это [parse_mode](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/bot.py#L457), он не может распознать содержимое строки users и ругается.

```
def send_message(
        self,
        chat_id: Union[int, str],
        text: str,
        parse_mode: ODVInput[str] = DEFAULT_NONE,
        .....
```

Comment: спасибо, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Как уже ответили  третий аргумент `send_message()` это `parse_mode`. Ваше сообщение должно быть передано вторым аргументом - `text`. Так же не нужно приводить `data` и `users` к строке, они уже в файле хранятся в виде строк. Да и хранить данные в файле это плохая практика, лучше использовать базы данных.

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['rate'])
async def rate(message: types.Message):
    f = open('rating.txt')
    data = f.readline()
    users = f.readline()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'команда работает {data} : {users}')
```